# Remove an entire row/column of atomic vector in R

Tags: r, vector, statistics

How can I remove an entire column/row of an atomic vector in **R**?

Everything I found about this on Q&A sites won't work...

Everytime I get a different error:

1. `:= is not an operator`
2. `$ not working on atomic vectors`
3. `number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`

This is my data

```
> print(nominalTable)

            MORTGAGE NONE OTHER OWN RENT
  36 months      854    1     4 165  928
  60 months      294    0     1  35  218
```

I want to remove the `NONE` and `OTHER` columns so that the `mosaicplot` would ignore them.

**UPDATE**

```
> dput(nominalTable)
structure(c(854L, 294L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 165L, 35L, 928L, 218L
), .Dim = c(2L, 5L), .Dimnames = structure(list(c("36 months", 
"60 months"), c("MORTGAGE", "NONE", "OTHER", "OWN", "RENT")), .Names = c("", 
"")), class = "table")
```

Comment: Is `nominalTable` a matrix? If so `$` operator is not defined - it is used to access elements from a list, whereas a matrix is just a vector with `dim` attributes (i.e. defining the rows and columns). Try `class(nominalTable)` to see what it is. And you may like to try `nominalTable[,"NONE"] <- NULL`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the names of the columns to keep, e.g.:

```
> nominalTable[, c('MORTGAGE', 'OWN', 'RENT')]

            MORTGAGE OWN RENT
  36 months      854 165  928
  60 months      294  35  218
```

Or remove the unwanted columns by their ids:

```
> nominalTable[, -(2:3)]

            MORTGAGE OWN RENT
  36 months      854 165  928
  60 months      294  35  218
```

See `?'['` for more details.

Comment: well it worked.. no idea what it does but it worked.. thank you.. I've updated the question with `dput(data)` for further viewers.

Comment: Or `nominalTable[,-(2:3)]`

Comment: @MatthewLundberg: thanks, you are right, that's a lot neater solution. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can assign NULL value to variables

```
Mort <- read.table(
  header=TRUE, text='
MORTGAGE NONE OTHER OWN RENT
36_months      854    1     4 165  928
60_months      294    0     1  35  218')
names(Mort) # 5 variables
# [1] "MORTGAGE" "NONE"     "OTHER"    "OWN"      "RENT"
Mort$NONE <- Mort$OTHER <- NULL # set both to NULL
names(Mort) # 3 variables now
#[1] "MORTGAGE" "OWN"      "RENT"
```

Answer (score 0):

This works too:

```
subset.matrix(nominalTable,select=-c(NONE,OTHER))
```

(it would be nice if just plain `subset` worked, but it doesn't quite understand tables properly)